# Android Button receives OnTouch event but not OnClick

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I have the following layout in which I'm trying to register an OnClickListener for the button `list_item_setup_step_button_start`. the Button receives touch events but no click events. any help is appreciated.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/list_item_setup_step_layout_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_item_setup_step_label"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/list_item_setup_state_label_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@color/activity_setup_step_state_next_color"
        android:clickable="false"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_item_setup_step_frame_layout_progress"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/list_item_setup_step_progress_bar_size"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.mikhaellopez.circularprogressbar.CircularProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/list_item_setup_step_progress_bar"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            app:cpb_background_progressbar_color="#FFCDD2"
            app:cpb_progressbar_color="#F44336"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/list_item_setup_step_button_start"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:padding="@dimen/text_margin_normal"
            android:background="@color/color_accent_default"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color_light"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_normal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/text_margin_normal"/>

    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/list_item_setup_step_label"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/list_item_setup_step_frame_layout_progress"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/text_margin_normal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_setup_step_text_view_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color_light"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_setup_step_text_view_status"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color_light" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

this is the code for the listener (I have a custom ScrollView which ignores touch events so that it can only be scrolled programmatically), the 'Clicked' log never appears and the functions aren't called.

```
private void handleStartButton() {
    currentStepStartButton = (Button) stepViews[currentPhase][currentStep].findViewById(R.id.list_item_setup_step_button_start);
    currentStepStartButton.setTypeface(BaseActivity.getFont(this));
    final TextView status = (TextView) stepViews[currentPhase][currentStep].findViewById(R.id.list_item_setup_step_text_view_status);
    progressBar = (CircularProgressBar) stepViews[currentPhase][currentStep].findViewById(R.id.list_item_setup_step_progress_bar) ;
    progressBar.setProgress(0);
    StyleHelper.applyStyle(this, progressBar);
    status.setTypeface(BaseActivity.getFont(this));
    if(currentStep == 0 && currentPhase == 0) {
        status.setText(getString(R.string.activity_setup_press_button_to_begin));
        currentStepStartButton.setText(getString(R.string.commons_start));
    } else {
        status.setText(getString(R.string.activity_setup_press_button_to_continue));
        currentStepStartButton.setText(getString(R.string.commons_start));
    }
    currentStepStartButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    currentStepStartButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e(Constants.DEBUG_TAG, "Clicked") ;
            currentStepStartButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            handleCurrentStepAction();
        }
    });
}
```

EDIT:

The following method was being called before the method which set the listener:

```
private void requestPermissions() {
        int currentAPIVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT ;
        if (currentAPIVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{
                    android.Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS,
                    android.Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS
            }, 1);
        }
    }
```

Once this method was removed, the `OnClickListener` started working again. I don't really have any idea why. Any theories ?

Comment: This is in a ListView? Then that's the problem. The ListView consumes the click before reaching the button

Comment: @cricket_007 As mentioned in the question, its in a custom ScrollView which doesn't consume events itself.

Comment: The parent FrameLayout has `android:clickable="false"`, maybe that is not letting it pass the onClick down to the button. Check whether setting it to true fixes it.

Comment: @Vucko The FrameLayout with clickable set to false isn't a parent of the Button in question. Anyway I removed that and its still the same.

Comment: Oh, I see. I mistook those 2 FrameLayouts :D Hm interesting then...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I faced the same problem while working on another project and figured what was really wrong here.

The problem, as suggested in the question itself, rises from the use of `requestPermissions` method. Although calling this method in case the permission its trying to acquire is already granted might seem to not show a dialog over the current activity, some invisible overlay seems to be added anyway which also appears to be clickable.

The solution hence is to always check if one already has the permissions one is trying to acquire and only fire up `requestPermissions` in case those permissions are not granted yet.

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be some interference from your other code (which is not visible in this question) since the button click method works if the code you provided, **except** for those parts which are not visible, is inserted into a new project.

Java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_2);

    final Button currentStepStartButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.list_item_setup_step_button_start);
    currentStepStartButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    currentStepStartButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Clicked");
            currentStepStartButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/list_item_setup_step_layout_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_item_setup_step_frame_layout_progress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/list_item_setup_step_button_start"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:clickable="true"/>

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Try to temporarily disable unnecessary features for the button to work to zero in on the issue.

Comment: I did and I somehow found the source of the problem, but I don't know why and how it affects the Button. Please check the edited question.