# SwipeRefreshLayout blocks onClickCallback of item in nested RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclick, swiperefreshlayout

I have a SwipeRefreshLayout with a nested RecyclerView. Each item in the recycler view essentially is a CardView with an onClickHandler attached. I have an issue where my clickHandler is not called if the recycler view is scrolled to the very top. If I scroll one px down I can click on things.

After adding printout statements on touch events and on click events it seems as if the swipe refresh layout will also intercept the touch event and `setTargetOffsetTopAndBottom`. This calls `requestLayout` which eventually seems to lead to an `ACTION_CANCEL` event. If I scroll down the recycler view 1px `canChildScrollUp()` will return true and stop the `requestLayout` call by the SwipRefreshLayout.

```
// SwipeRefreshLayout.java
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    ...
    if (!isEnabled() || mReturningToStart || canChildScrollUp()
            || mRefreshing || mNestedScrollInProgress) {
        // Fail fast if we're not in a state where a swipe is possible
        return false;
    }
    ...
    switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            setTargetOffsetTopAndBottom(mOriginalOffsetTop - mCircleView.getTop());
            mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(0);
            mIsBeingDragged = false;

            pointerIndex = ev.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
            if (pointerIndex < 0) {
                return false;
            }
            mInitialDownY = ev.getY(pointerIndex);
            break;
    ...
```

Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/ticket_wallet_refresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/ticket_wallet_recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:itemCount="3"
        tools:listheader="@layout/ticket_header_item"
        tools:listitem="@layout/active_ticket_item" />
</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

ViewHolder

```
sealed class FooViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

    abstract fun bind(item: WalletItem)

    class ActiveFooViewHolder(
        view: View,
        private val remainingTimeFormatter: RemainingTimeFormatter,
        private val callback: (Int) -> Unit
    ) : FooViewHolder(view) {

        init {
            view.setOnClickListener {
                callback(adapterPosition)
            }
   ...
```

My compile target is Android API lvl 29.

Answer (score 4):

I have been experiencing the same issue. I did have a `ConstraintLayout` wrapping the `SwipeRefreshLayout`. When I removed the `ConstraintLayout` (replaced it with `LinearLayout`) the issue fixed. Hope that helps. I have no idea why it is working.

Comment: Setting parent layout with LinearLayout fixes the issue.

Comment: For me this works! I can change ConstraintLayout with LinearLayout.

I tried nesting layouts:
- ConstraintLayout>LinearLayout>SwipeRefreshLayout does not work.
I tried putting a margin/padding on the elements:

- Putting a padding on the SwipeRefreshLayout works! Margin does not work. It must be top or bottom; start/end/left/right does not work. It can be 1px, 0.1px or even smaller, until a specific degree. 
This is very weird. Looks like a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar issue. In my case, the onClick was blocked for a number of seconds and then magically returned. Scrolling might have solved it as well but I didn't have enough items to scroll them (in my app I was showing 3-5 Bluetooth devices). OnTouch was activated successfully; onClick was not.

I tried the answer proposed here and it didn't help. Neither did [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41742935/android-button-receives-ontouch-event-but-not-onclick) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283293/ontouch-works-but-onclicklistener-doesnt).

What unexpectedly solved the issue was using `notifyItemInserted(int position)` in my `addDevice(BluetoothDevice device)` function instead of `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

I have no idea why this worked. My RecyclerView held maybe 5 devices, I find it difficult to believe that notifying that the dataset changed takes up to 20 seconds.

In more detail:

My code is based on the [Android example](https://github.com/android/connectivity-samples/tree/master/BluetoothLeGatt). In the example, in the [DeviceScanActivity](https://github.com/android/connectivity-samples/blob/master/BluetoothLeGatt/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/bluetoothlegatt/DeviceScanActivity.java), there is the following code:

```
@Override
        public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mLeDeviceListAdapter.addDevice(device);
                    mLeDeviceListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
        }
```

removing the line `notifyDataSetChanged()` and adding `notifyItemInserted(<position of new device>)` inside the `addData` function within the adapter solved the issue.